# Java Protobuf in Android - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I'm building an Android app in ADT v21.0.0.  This application needs to use a protobuf library I've compiled into a jar.

By putting this jar as well as protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar in my libs/ folder, Eclipse recognizes it at build time, however whenever I attempt to run the application in my Android emulator, I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception when attempting to instantiate one of my auto-generated custom classes produced by the protobuf compiler.

I've seen a lot of tips regarding the naming of the libs/ folder (apparently a prior ADT update broke this by requiring the /lib folder to be /libs), as well as adding .jars explicitly from the "Java Build Path" settings window (and checking the jars in the Order and Export pane).

None of these have helped, however, and I'm wondering if there's something more fundamental preventing my protobuf classes from being recognized at runtime.

Note: if I create a standard Java application in Eclipse, I am able to use my proto classes just fine.  This is only an issue when running the Android application.

Comment: Please update your question to include the full name of the class that was not found.

Comment: It's a custom class auto-generated from my protobuf message specs, so I'm not sure if it will help.  However, I edited the post to state this directly.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add the print stack trace in your post.

Comment: How are you instantiating your auto-generated protobuf class?

Answer (score 0):

seems that your project import some library what your auto-generated jar depends..and is not on device or emulator..